# Image not displaying possibly due to not being saved in the file path

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

So I am currently trying to save an image and displaying that image in the app. However, the image is not being displayed. I'm not sure if it is due to the image not being saved correctly or some other problem. When I add the line, `self.image.image = bach`, the image displays correctly. However, when I comment that line out, the image does not display. But, I think, it is supposed to be displayed since I saved the data in the variable `savePath`. And therefore, `self.image.image = UIImage(named: savePath)`, should cause my app to display the correct image.  Any suggestions on how to fix this problem?

Here is the code:

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  Downloading An Image From The Web
//
//  Created by Jae Hyun Kim on 9/6/15.
//  Copyright © 2015 Jae Hyun Kim. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var image: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let url = NSURL(string: "http://7-themes.com/data_images/out/3/6776407-beautiful-scenery-pictures.jpg")
        let urlRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)

        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(urlRequest, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
            if error != nil {
                print(error)
            }
            else {
                if let bach = UIImage(data: data!) {
                    //self.image.image = bach
                    let documentsDirectory:String?
                    let paths:[AnyObject] = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentationDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask(), true)
                    if paths.count > 0 {
                        documentsDirectory = paths[0] as? String
                        let savePath = documentsDirectory! + "/bach.jpg"
                        NSFileManager.defaultManager().createFileAtPath(savePath, contents: data, attributes: nil)
                        self.image.image = UIImage(named: savePath)
                    }
                }
            }
        })
        task!.resume()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem there is thatUIImage(named:) is for images at your resources. If you want to load your image from disk you need to use UIImage(contentsOfFile:).

Try like this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var image: UIImageView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let url = NSURL(string: "http://7-themes.com/data_images/out/3/6776407-beautiful-scenery-pictures.jpg")!
        let urlRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url)

        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(urlRequest, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in


            // you should always do it from the main queue otherwise you will experience a big delay when trying to display your image
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                // unwrap your data
                if let data = data {
                    println(data.length)
                    // get your document directory URL
                    let documentDirectory = NSFileManager().URLForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomain: .UserDomainMask, appropriateForURL: nil, create: true, error: nil)!
                    // create your local file url by appending your url last path component
                    let fileUrl = documentDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent(url.lastPathComponent!)
                    // save downloaded data to disk
                    if data.writeToURL(fileUrl, atomically: true) {
                        println(true)
                        // load your saved image from disk
                        self.image.image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: fileUrl.path!)
                    }

                }
            }

        })
        task.resume()
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I don't think that's the problem because I did this:                         if NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(savePath) {
                            print("file available")
                        }
                        else {
                            print("file not available")
                        }. And it keeps printing to the console "file not available"

Comment: So you have more than one problem I will show you how to save your file once I get a chance

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. I did some more trial and error and I was able to pinpoint the problem, which is described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32420656/nsfilemanager-defaultmanager-createfileatpath-returning-false. I would like to see if there is a solution for the code that I already wrote.

Comment: One thing though, I thought NSURLSession already was async. The apple developer guide states, `Like most networking APIs, the NSURLSession API is highly asynchronous.` So why dispatch? Maybe the dispatch that you provided specifies that it will be on the main thread?

Comment: You need to update the UI from the main thread. Try it without it to see the delay to update the image

Comment: I'm getting an error for the `let documentDirectory = NSFileManager().URLForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomain: .UserDomainMask, appropriateForURL: nil, create: true, error: nil)!` saying Extra argument 'error' in call.

Comment: Leo, I know this is a little weird but I have some general questions regarding iOS development that I would LOVE to ask you. Is it possible for us to move this discussion to a chat?

Comment: @Jae Were you able to resolve this? I tried out all the suggestions in the comments and also in [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32420656/nsfilemanager-defaultmanager-createfileatpath-returning-false) to no avail. I believe my issue is at 'self.image.image = UIImage(named: savePath)' as well. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

For the line

```
let paths:[AnyObject] = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentationDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask, true)
```

you have to put `NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask`. So the entire line of code should be

```
let paths:[AnyObject] = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentationDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask, true)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had an error alike trying to use ***.DocumentationDirectory*** instead of ***.DocumentDirectory***.

> NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains

method just builds the paths but doesn't check for availability|existence and you could be trying to write on an inexisting directory.